# To use this site, please enable Javascript

Tags: google-chrome

I have the following message popping up when trying to grab the json requests from a website:

```
To use this site, please enable Javascript.
```

I have double checked with my chrome browser and javascript is currently enabled. Please advise on what I should do to correct this following issue?

Here's the website I'm trying to scrape:
[transfrmarket](https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop)

Here's an example of the response above:
[image]

I know that Javascript is enabled on my google chrome as I tried disabling it and accessing this site but I cannot enter. Therefore, it's enabled but for some reason I get the message as shown above. This works perfectly fine when using safari however.

Comment: What website? Grab “json requests” how? Please provide screenshots.

Comment: @DanielB I have updated the post. it's just a simple scraper with using `scrapy`, I've done it before on this site but I don't know why the message is appearing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mistaken about the technology. Just because a page is fetching data in the background does not mean this data is JSON or XML. And in this case, it isn’t. Instead, a complete HTML page is returned. This page happens to contain a `<noscript>` tag:

```html
   <noscript>
        <style>
            html body *:not(.noscript) {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="noscript">
            To use this site, please enable Javascript.        </div>
    </noscript>
```

Because the preview window does not execute scripts, the `<noscript>` tag “triggers” and its contents are displayed.

To see the response in Chrome Dev Tools, use the *Response* tab. To see the response in Firefox Dev Tools, toggle the *Raw* switch.